# How can I serialize a closure in Perl?

Tags: perl, serialization, function, closures, store

I think this might be best asked using an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Storable qw(nstore retrieve);

local $Storable::Deparse = 1;
local $Storable::Eval    = 1;

sub sub_generator {
    my ($x) = @_;

    return sub {
        my ($y) = @_;
        return $x + $y;
    };
}

my $sub = sub_generator(1000);
say $sub->(1); # gives 1001
nstore( $sub, "/tmp/sub.store" );
$sub = retrieve("/tmp/sub.store");
say $sub->(1); # gives 1
```

When I dump `/tmp/sub.store` I see:

```
$VAR1 = sub {
            package Storable;
            use warnings;
            use strict 'refs';
            my($y) = @_;
            return $x + $y;
        }
```

But `$x` is never defined in this sub. I would expect that the sub generated by `sub_generator` will have `$x` replaced with its actual value upon generation. How should I solve this?

Note this question relates to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845134).

Comment: Perhaps it is time to step back and consider whether serializing subs is a good idea? I have rarely encountered a need to do such a thing in my career.

Comment: @Ether I adopted the suggestion to use an object instead. For some reason I was tending to avoid objects in Perl, until you guys introduced my to Moose, which makes everything much nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think [`Storable`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Storable/) works with closures.   However there are other CPAN modules that will serialise a closure.  For eg. [`Data::Dump::Streamer`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dump-Streamer/)

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump::Streamer;

sub sub_generator {
    my ($x) = @_;

    return sub {
        my ($y) = @_;
        return $x + $y;
    };
}

my $sub = sub_generator(1000);
say $sub->(1); # gives 1001

my $serialised = Dump( $sub )->Out;
my $copy = do {
    my $CODE1 = undef;
    eval $serialised;
    $CODE1;
};

say $copy->(2); # gives 1002
say $sub->(1);  # still gives 1001
```

This is what the serialised code looks like when printed here, `say Dump $sub;`:

```
my ($x);
$x = 1000;
$CODE1 = sub {
           use warnings;
           use strict 'refs';
           BEGIN {
             $^H{'feature_unicode'} = q(1);
             $^H{'feature_say'} = q(1);
             $^H{'feature_state'} = q(1);
             $^H{'feature_switch'} = q(1);
           }
           my($y) = @_;
           return $x + $y;
         };
```

**Update**

See this thread [Storable and Closures](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2006/03/msg110979.html) on the Perl5 porters mailing list.  It confirms what I thought about [`Storable`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Storable/) and closures.

/I3az/

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I get an empty file: `use Data::Dump::Streamer; my $h={A=>1, B=>2}; open (my $fh, ">", "/tmp/DEL"); Dump($h)->To($fh) or die; close ($fh);`